# Final print statement returning null (java)

Tags: java, class, parsing, constructor

I have a basic name application that is taking in user data from the main class, splits the data in the parser class and then tries to assign everything in the final class and print it out in the toString method. I know the main class and the parser are working fine. I have verified in the parser class that the data DOES split properly and also sends the data through the object I made to the final class to assign it all. However, my final code is returning null..

MAIN CLASS

---

```
            import java.util.Scanner;
            public class MainClass {
                public static void main (String[]args)
                {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //create scanner object to gather name information
                    String fullName = null; //set the predefined value for the users name to null
                    nameParse splitInformation = new nameParse(); //method build to split the name into different sections
                    SecondClass access = new SecondClass(); //class built to output the different name data

                    System.out.println("What is your name?");

                    fullName = input.nextLine(); //store the users name and pass it into the data parser

                    splitInformation.parseNameInformation(fullName); //name parsing parameters built

                    System.out.println(access.toString());





                }

            }
```

Data Parser Class

---

```
            public class nameParse {
                private String firstName;
                private String middleName;
                private String lastName;

                public nameParse()
                {
                    firstName = "initial";
                    middleName = "initial";
                    lastName = "initial";
                }

                public void parseNameInformation(String inputInfo)
                {

                    //Create an array to store the data and split it into multiple sectors
                    String nameInformation[] = inputInfo.split("\\s");

                    firstName = nameInformation[0];
                    middleName = nameInformation[1];
                    lastName = nameInformation[2];

                    //System.out.println(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);

                    SecondClass sendData = new SecondClass();

                    sendData.setFirstName(firstName);
                    sendData.setMiddleName(middleName);
                    sendData.setLastName(lastName);


                }

            }
```

Final Class
__

```
    public class SecondClass {

        private String firstName;
        private String middleName;
        private String lastName;


        /*public String GFN()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String GMN()
        {
            return middleName;
        }

        public String GLN()
        {
            return lastName;
        }*/
        public String setFirstName(String yourFirstName)
        {
            firstName = yourFirstName;
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public String setMiddleName(String yourMiddleName)
        {
            middleName = yourMiddleName;
            return this.middleName;
        }

        public String setLastName(String yourLastName)
        {
            lastName = yourLastName;
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public String getFN()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String printNameInfo = "\nYour First Name:\t" + getFN();
            return printNameInfo;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set any of your SecondClass object's (called "access") fields, so of course they'll all be null.

So in short, your code creates a nameParse object, gets information from the user, but does nothing with that information. You create a SecondClass object called access, put no data into it, and so should expect no valid data in it when you try to print it out. Solution: put information into your SecondClass object first. Call its setter methods:

```
// be sure to call the setter methods before trying to print anything out:
access.setSomething(something);
access.setSomethingElse(somethingElse);
```

---

**Edit**
You state:

> I thought I set the data using the sendData.setFirstname(...) etc?

In the `parseNameInformation` method you create a new SecondClass object and you do set the fields of this object, but this object is completely distinct from the one in your main method whose fields are still null. To solve this, give parseNameInformation a method parameter and pass in your main method's SecondClass object into it and set its methods. You'll have to create the SecondClass object *before* calling the method of course.

i.e.,

```
public void parseNameInformation(String inputInfo, SecondClass sendData)
{
    //Create an array to store the data and split it into multiple sectors
    String nameInformation[] = inputInfo.split("\\s");

    firstName = nameInformation[0];
    middleName = nameInformation[1];
    lastName = nameInformation[2];

    //System.out.println(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);

    // SecondClass sendData = new SecondClass();  // !!! get rid of this

    sendData.setFirstName(firstName);
    sendData.setMiddleName(middleName);
    sendData.setLastName(lastName);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek: see edit to answer. Remember garbage in == garbage out. The object will only hold the data you give it.

Comment: I thought I set the data using the sendData.setFirstname(...) etc?

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek: see edit to answer. You are filling in a SecondClass object's fields, just the wrong SecondClass object.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly don't understand how I am supposed to do that whatsoever. I am looking at my code and it isn't making sense to me.

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek: did you see the edit to my answer? Again, you're creating a ***new*** SecondClass object inside of your method. This new object **has nothing to do with the first one inside of the main method**. This is a key concept that you need to grasp. Your job is not to create a new SecondClass object, but rather to change the state of the first one in the main method. That's why you may wish to pass it into this method.

Comment: Ok, awesome. I got it to work now. So if I am understanding this correctly, the method in the main class has the secondClass as a parameter so the data gets passed back into the method after it's assigned in the secondClass?

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek: no. When you pass in your SecondClass object into the method, you're passing in a reference to the original SecondClass object in main, and so the parameter points to the exact same object. Now you're filling in the fields of the original object. Now make sure that these changes conform to your homework instructions. It might make better sense for the parseNameInformation method to return a SecondClass object, in which case you would not give it a SecondClass parameter, and you *would* create a new object in the method and then return it.

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't for any homework assignment. I am just trying to make fake ideas to help me to study for my exam. Thanks for the coding explanations and additional help!